# How to create UNIQUE KEY by part of field please?

Tags: mysql

My environment is Server version: 5.1.72-community MySQL Community Server (GPL).

An example:

```
CREATE TABLE `pe` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `height` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` double(5,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pe_time` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_id` (`person_id`,`pe_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I have some rows in table pe, some of them like:

```
person_id, height, weight, pe_time

10051, 160, 55, '2017-10-20'

10052, 172, 60, '2018-01-09'
```

Now, given a new row like:

```
person_id, height, weight, pe_time

10052, 172, 61, '2018-01-10'
```

Because there is a row which pe_time's year is 2018 and the person_id = 10052, so I want to update that row, set each field as the new value.

But, given a new row like:

```
person_id, height, weight, pe_time

10051, 161, 57, '2018-01-10'
```

Because there is not a row which pe_time's year is 2018 and the person_id = 10051, so I want to insert the new row.

As this, I want the

```
UNIQUE KEY is `uk_id` (`person_id`,**`pe_time's year`**).
```

If no way to create that UNIQUE KEY, how to write the sql

```
INSERT INTO... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...
```

to do this please?

Comment: You will have to add a column with just the year and set this value in a trigger (or rather two triggers, one for insert and one for update) and define the unique index using this column. For MySQL 5.7+, you could use generated columns (without triggers, just a formula).

Comment: what do you want to update?

Comment: @Solarflare Thank you. I know the first way, but I can not add column on table. And can not update to MySQL 5.7 too.

Comment: @Sameera Thank you for your attention. I want to update the old_row by new_row, if old_row.person_id = new_row.person_id and YEAR(old_row) = YEAR(new_row), else, I want to insert the new_row.

Comment: why can't you delete the old row and insert the new row?

Comment: @Sameera Thank you. Because Foreign Keys, I can not delete the row.

Comment: If you cannot modify your table, you cannot use unique keys for this (unless you do not care about the value for pe_time, and always add the first of january of the year). You will probably have to fall back to do that check yourself: e.g. do a select first, and if the row exists, you update, otherwise you insert.

Comment: you can update it by using your auto incremented id right. that id is unique.